# Oracle sql script

Tags: sql

How can I write a SQL script for updating 10 row's dates for 10 different users?

Comment: Do you mean different Oracle Users? Which tend to ten different schemas?

Answer (score 2):

you can use IN operator

```
update table1
set date=<your date>
where userid in (1,2,3,.....10)
```

Comment: +1 Cheers, you read the question better than I did :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
update  users
set     name = 'Joe'
where   userid = 1

update  users
set     name = 'Mohammed'
where   userid = 2

Etc.
```

The hard way:

```
update  users
set     name = case when userid = 1 then 'Joe'
                    when userid = 2 then 'Mohammed'
                    ...
                    else name
               end
```

Comment: Where 'easy' and 'hard' are quite the personal experience. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
update Table_name set value = something
where column_name in (select values from list_table);
```

Here you all values in temp table and use that table as mentioned above.